# Change Activity behaviour when C2DM Push notification is received

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have a working server/client solution that sends push notification to my device. The next step for my project would be to show a dialog on the activity window when the onReceive event is called in the `C2DMReceiver` class.

As I am new to android, I have no idea how to do this, so I would be really happy if someone could explain this to me.

Basically I reused the classes from the chrometophone Application for c2dm. The onReceive event is called, as I create a log entry for logcat. As the `C2DMReceiver` is a service, how to I get informed on my activity if there is a new message?

I googled a lot but couldn't find a working solution... I tried to use the `registerReceiver()` but I'm pretty sure I did it wrong. Does anyone have an example?

Ok, so here is what I got so far:

**Activity**

```
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "Test");
      }
    };

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "started");

    }

    // Called when the activity is restarted
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addCategory("com.mydomain.myapp.CONTEXT");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    // Called when the activity is closed
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
```

C2DMReceiver
public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {

```
public C2DMReceiver() {
    super("my_test@gmail.com");

    // TODO Load dynamic Gmail address
}

@Override
public void onRegistrered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, registrationId);

    // Store the registration id in the preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = Prefs.get(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("deviceRegistrationID", registrationId);
    editor.commit();

    // TODO: Send ID to server
}

@Override
public void onUnregistered(Context context) {
    Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "got here!");
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, errorId);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "C2DMReceiver: " + intent.getStringExtra("payload"));

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("com.mydomain.myapp.NEWMESSAGE");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("reading", intent.getStringExtra("payload"));
    broadcastIntent.addCategory("com.mydomain.myapp.CONTEXT");
    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}

}
```

This is all I got, but I never receive my own broadcast.. Does anyone have some inputs?

Comment: Just for clarification, the line `Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "C2DMReceiver: " + intent.getStringExtra("payload"));`is reached, right?

Comment: yes it is! I can see what I pushed to the device with logcat

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Log.w(Consts.LOG_TAG_SERVICE, "C2DMReceiver: " + intent.getStringExtra("payload"));

  Intent i = new Intent(context, YourMainActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("reading", intent.getStringExtra("payload"));
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(i);

}
```

You then handle the intent in your onStart in your main activity. If your activity is already running, it will be handled by the existing instance, if not, a new instance will be started.

Comment: Or, you could follow this guide to make a status bar notification, so that the user can select whether to start your app. Might be a cleaner way to do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html